# Reference for the Existence of Regular Models in Characteristic Zero

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $R$ be a DVR with fraction field $K$ and residue field $k$ of characteristic zero.

The following result about the existence of regular models for varieties over $K$ seems to be well-known:

**Theorem:** Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $K$.  Then there exists a regular model $\pi: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ such that $\pi$ is proper, the generic fiber of $\mathcal{X}$ is isomorphic to $X$, and the central fiber $\mathcal{X}_0$
is a union of smooth components (possibly with multiplicity) that intersect transversely.

My understanding is that this follows from the existence of resolutions of singularities in characteristic zero, but where did this statement first appear?  How does it follow from the existence of resolutions?